# Find a system of recurrence relation for computing the number of n-digit binary sequences with exactly one pair of consecutive 0s.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I tried solving this question from Alan Tucker's book, "Applied Combinatorics, 6th edition", Page no.294, Problem-35, but could not solve it.
I was thinking of finding the number of n-digit binary sequences which have at least two pairs of consecutive 0s and then subtracting the sum of both the number of ways to get no consecutive zeroes from $ 2^{n}$.
Am I correct with this approach?

Comment: My recursion approach would be to let $A_n$ denote the number of binary sequences with exactly 1 set of consecutive $0$'s (somewhere) that ends in $0$.  Then $B_n$ is the same as $A_n$ except that it ends in $1$.  Then, $C_n$ ends in $0$ but has no occurrence of consecutive $0$'s.  Then $D_n$ is the same as $C_n$ but it ends in $1$.  Then, I would compute $A_{n+1}, B_{n+1}, C_{n+1}, D_{n+1},~$ based on $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$, with the idea that $A_n + B_n$ is the desired computation.  So, I would end up dragging along $4$ variables, going from $n$ to $(n+1)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: I would start by manually computing $A_k, B_k, C_k, D_k$ for $k \in \{2,3,4\}$ each in two ways, by a proposed formula, and manually.  This would verify that the formulas **work**.  Then, I would express $A_n + B_n$ as a function of $n$, and I am **done**.

Comment: There may be an easier recursion approach, but value has to be given to an approach that the student regards as sensible and easy to understand.  The above comments work for me, while others might be more comfortable with a different recursion approach.  Also, your problem's title specifically uses the term recurrence.  There may be other (non-recurrence) approaches, but I suspect that recurrence is best, for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a more elaborate version of the comments by @user2661923. Spoiler: this is sequence [A001629](http://oeis.org/A001629) in the OEIS.

These kind of questions can be approached quite mechanically by modeling them with a suitable state transition diagram. (It might not always be the easiest or most clever approach, but it *always* works.) Each state represents a specific category of sequences and counts the number of sequences of length $n$ that fall into that category.  A state transition matrix relates these states for length $n+1$ to those for length $n$.  In this case four states can be defined as follows

1. The sequence ends with a zero and has no consecutive zeroes.
2. The sequence ends with a one and has no consecutive zeroes.
3. The sequence ends with a zero and contains precisely one pair of consecutive zeroes.
4. The sequence ends with a one and contains precisely one pair of consecutive zeroes.

The state transition matrix is then $$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

For sequences of length $1$ the state vector $v_1$  equals $$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then for length $n+1$ the state vector is given by $$v_{n+1} = M v_n = M^n v_1.$$ The number $a_n$ of sequence of length $n$ that we’re looking for is then the sum of the last two numbers in the state vector $v_n$ (so the sum of numbers in state $3$ and state $4$).

The sequence of state vectors begins as $$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 8 \\ 5 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 13 \\ 10 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}, \ldots$$

and the requested number $a_n$ of sequences is therefore $$0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, \ldots$$

There is also a simple linear recursion for this sequence. Note that the characteristic polynomial of $M$ equals $$\det(xI - M) = x^4 -2 x^3 - x^2 + 2 x + 1$$ and therefore the sequence satisfies the recursion $$a_{n+4}=2 a_{n+3}+ a_{n+2} - 2 a_{n+1} - a_n.$$